# Harmonic voltage source, how to calculate it

Tags: harmonics

I have this scheme.
[image]

I have all the parameters:
L1=110 uH

C1=160 nF

C2=5 nF

Rt=1.2 kΩ

ω1=45290 rad/s

ω2=162089 rad/s

ω3=238366 rad/s

ω4=276982 rad/s

But I dont understand how to calculate the voltage source. I have this formula for it:
[image]
So my job is to calculate \$ i_{2}^1 \$ in harmonic \$w_{1}\$, \$ i_{2}^2 \$ in harmonic \$w_{2}\$, 
\$ i_{2}^3 \$ in harmonic \$w_{3}\$, \$ i_{2}^4 \$ in harmonic \$w_{4}\$.

**QUESTION:**
I don't get how to calculate this voltage source. I'm not sure how to replace sin(wt), what's the the time(t)?

Comment: Smells of XY - ultimately what are you trying to achieve with this question?

Comment: What is XY? I'm trying to solve my problem for university.

Comment: [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: Seems like it's not. I added all the info just to not waste time for any further questions, if it somehow happens.

Comment: Do you want to know what \$sin(\omega_n\cdot t)\$ means? \$\omega_{1-5}\$ are not harmonics BTW. \$i_2^4\$ reads as the 4th power of \$i_2\$ - is that actually what you mean?

Comment: What do you mean? I wasn't sure what to do the other harmonics when I replace the n-th one. Now I'm reading about how to calculate the current through components in sinusoidal circuits. It's not power, it's in brace, sorry i coudln't type it. \$i_{2}^(4)\$

Comment: Well, kinda expected it. Out of context btw. 
In my tasks it's written harmonic \$w_{1-4}\$ ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use superposition and calculate each component of i2 individually.  Each of the different frequency components of the source will be 5@0 degrees.